# Can't import Python module

Tags: python

I have created the following Python 3 module named resource.py, with two functions, Read_Cursor and Write_Cursor.  When I import the module, I get an error, depending on how I import the module.

I have tried:

```
import resource
from resource import *
Read_Cursor=resource.Read_Cursor
```

resource.py:

```
def Write_Cursor(Cursor):
        with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","w") as f: # Set the Cursor position

def Read_Cursor():
        with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","r") as f:   # Get the Cursor position
                C = int(f.read())
        return C
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./index.py", line 6, in <module>
    import resource
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resource.py", line 5
    def Read_Cursor():
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: The file `resource.py` is not indented properly. Use a linter like `PyLint` to figure out why.

Comment: It just returns:  ************* Module cgi-bin.resource
E:  5, 0: expected an indented block (syntax-error)  That's not terribly helpful.

Comment: General tip: If the interpreter says that it "expected" something, and it points to the beginning of the line, then the error is on the previous line more often than not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually at previous line:

```py
with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","w") as f: # Set the Cursor position`
```

The *with* statement is incomplete (check [[Python.Docs]: Compound statements - The with statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)).

To correct it, do something like:

```py
def Write_Cursor(Cursor):
    with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor", "w") as f: # Set the Cursor position
        f.write(str(Cursor))  # Just an example, I don't know how Cursor should be serialized
```

Also, as pointed out by others, you should use ***4** SPACE*s for indentation (as recommended in [[Python]: PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code - Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)):

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Comment: Oops!  How the heck did that happen?  I cut-and-pasted the code from a working copy.  Somehow I drppped the write code.  Pfft!  Oh, and you guessed the code correctly.

Comment: Sometimes it happens :)

Answer (score -2):

You got incorrect indented blocks, in Python it is 4 spaces or 1 tabulation

*corrected code:*

```
def Write_Cursor(Cursor):
    with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","w") as f: # Set the Cursor position

def Read_Cursor():
    with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","r") as f:   # Get the Cursor position
        C = int(f.read())
    return C
```

Comment: this does nothing to fix the real problem, that there is no code inside the `with` statement in `Write_Cursor`

Comment: Although *PEP 8* recommends 4 spaces, (if not enforced), **any** indentation can be used, as long it's consistent. The answer is incorrect. -1.

Comment: Correct!  You have sharp eyes.  Like everyone else, I was looking at the indents.  It never occurred to me  I had left out the write.