# Can't get FontForge to import as a module in a custom Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, virtualenv, fontforge

I have the following script:

```
import fontforge
import os.path
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: [FONT] [OUTPUTDIR]")
    exit(1)

fontpath = sys.argv[1]
font     = fontforge.open(fontpath)
outdir   = sys.argv[2]

if os.path.exists(outdir):
    pass
elif os.access(os.path.dirname(outdir), os.W_OK):
    os.makedirs(outdir)
else:
    exit(1)

for name in font:
    filename = name + ".svg"
    outfull = os.path.join(outdir,filename)
    font[name].export(outfull)
```

The script dumps all glyphs to individual SVG files in a folder.

Anyway, I've installed the latest windows version of FontForge.

From what I understand, FontForge embeds python, and the binary is `ffpython.exe`. So you should be able to call `ffpython myscript.py {arg1 arg2 arg3}`

The problem is that this doesn't work.

When I do `ffpython myscript.py arg1 arg2`, I get an error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fontforge: The specified procedure could not be found.`

You can also result with the same error by simply invoking `ffpython` and then typing `import fontforge` directly into the interpreter.

There is a batch file that comes with FontForge located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\fontforge-console.bat`.

If I run this batch file, it sets some variables and then opens a console window. If I *then* call ffpython in that console window and enter `import fontforge`, everything magically works as expected.

But this is a really limited and improper solution. I don't want to have to open this magical batch file every time I want to run a Python script that interfaces with FontForge.

So here's my question:

How can I get FontForge properly installed as a module in Python? How can I get a python script to import the fontforge module when being run via ffpython?

I would greatly appreciate any help at all.

### Edit:

Running the test script by @CristiFati from an Admin PowerShell prompt where the PWD is not the same as ffpython (Failure):

```
03-14 20:06:09 D:\> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\ffpython.exe' .\code00.py
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\ffpython.exe
Version: 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit]
CWD: D:\
UName: None
PATH: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python\Python310\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\BIN;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\GitHub CLI\;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2020.1.1;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin;C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\myusername\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\
PYTHONHOME: None
PYTHONPATH: None
sys.path: ['D:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload', 'D:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code00.py", line 12, in <module>
    import fontforge as ff
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fontforge: The specified procedure could not be found.
03-14 20:06:24 D:\>
```

Same results occur if I use CMD.

Running the test script by @CristiFati from an Admin PowerShell prompt where the PWD is `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin` (Success):

```
03-14 20:16:08 C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin> ffpython D:\code00.py
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\ffpython.exe
Version: 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit]
CWD: C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin
UName: None
PATH: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python\Python310\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\BIN;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\GitHub CLI\;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2020.1.1;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin;C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\myusername\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\
PYTHONHOME: None
PYTHONPATH: None
sys.path: ['D:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages']
Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit] 032bit on win32

<module 'fontforge' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FontForgeBuilds\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages\\fontforge.pyd'>
['SpiroVersion', 'UnicodeAnnotationFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockCountFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockEndFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockNameFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockStartFromLib', 'UnicodeNameFromLib', 'UnicodeNames2FromLib', 'UnicodeNamesListVersion', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'activeFont', 'activeFontInUI', 'activeGlyph', 'activeLayer', 'ask', 'askChoices', 'askMulti', 'askString', 'awcontext', 'awglyph', 'configurePlugins', 'contour', 'cvt', 'defaultOtherSubrs', 'font', 'fonts', 'fontsInFile', 'getConvexNib', 'getPluginInfo', 'getPrefs', 'glyph', 'glyphPen', 'hasSpiro', 'hasUserInterface', 'hooks', 'layer', 'layer_array', 'layerinfo', 'layerinfo_array', 'loadEncodingFile', 'loadNamelist', 'loadNamelistDir', 'loadPlugins', 'loadPrefs', 'logWarning', 'math', 'mathKern', 'nameFromUnicode', 'onAppClosing', 'open', 'openFilename', 'parseTTInstrs', 'point', 'postError', 'postNotice', 'preloadCidmap', 'printSetup', 'private', 'readOtherSubrsFile', 'references', 'registerGlyphSeparationHook', 'registerImportExport', 'registerMenuItem', 'runInitScripts', 'saveFilename', 'savePrefs', 'scriptFromUnicode', 'scriptPath', 'selection', 'setConvexNib', 'setPrefs', 'spiroCorner', 'spiroG2', 'spiroG4', 'spiroLeft', 'spiroOpen', 'spiroRight', 'splineCorner', 'splineCurve', 'splineHVCurve', 'splineTangent', 'unParseTTInstrs', 'unicodeFromName', 'unitShape', 'unspecifiedMathValue', 'userConfigPath', 'version']

Done.
```

So I need to figure out why things are only working when my PWD is `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin`. I don't understand why it won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just installed *FontForge 20230101*. Using the following test script.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

print("Executable:", sys.executable)
print("Version:", sys.version)
print("CWD:", os.getcwd())
print("UName:", getattr(os, "uname", lambda: None)())
for evn in ("PATH", "PYTHONHOME", "PYTHONPATH"):
    print("{:s}: {:}".format(evn, os.environ.get(evn)))
print("sys.path:", sys.path)

import fontforge as ff


def main(*argv):
    print(ff)
    print(dir(ff))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> :: Run FFPython (full path)
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit] 032bit on win32
>
> Executable: c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe
> Version: 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit]
> CWD: E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592
> UName: None
> PATH: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
> PYTHONHOME: None
> PYTHONPATH: None
> sys.path: ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages']
> <module 'fontforge' from 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages\\fontforge.pyd'>
> ['SpiroVersion', 'UnicodeAnnotationFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockCountFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockEndFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockNameFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockStartFromLib', 'UnicodeNameFromLib', 'UnicodeNames2FromLib', 'UnicodeNamesListVersion', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'activeFont', 'activeFontInUI', 'activeGlyph', 'activeLayer', 'ask', 'askChoices', 'askMulti', 'askString', 'awcontext', 'awglyph', 'configurePlugins', 'contour', 'cvt', 'defaultOtherSubrs', 'font', 'fonts', 'fontsInFile', 'getConvexNib', 'getPluginInfo', 'getPrefs', 'glyph', 'glyphPen', 'hasSpiro', 'hasUserInterface', 'hooks', 'layer', 'layer_array', 'layerinfo', 'layerinfo_array', 'loadEncodingFile', 'loadNamelist', 'loadNamelistDir', 'loadPlugins', 'loadPrefs', 'logWarning', 'math', 'mathKern', 'nameFromUnicode', 'onAppClosing', 'open', 'openFilename', 'parseTTInstrs', 'point', 'postError', 'postNotice', 'preloadCidmap', 'printSetup', 'private', 'readOtherSubrsFile', 'references', '
> registerGlyphSeparationHook', 'registerImportExport', 'registerMenuItem', 'runInitScripts', 'saveFilename', 'savePrefs', 'scriptFromUnicode', 'scriptPath', 'selection', 'setConvexNib', 'setPrefs', 'spiroCorner', 'spiroG2', 'spiroG4', 'spiroLeft', 'spiroOpen', 'spiroRight', 'splineCorner', 'splineCurve', 'splineHVCurve', 'splineTangent', 'unParseTTInstrs', 'unicodeFromName', 'unitShape', 'unspecifiedMathValue', 'userConfigPath', 'version']
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: More tests (paths related)
> [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin
>
> [prompt]> :: Run FFPython (from PATH). Suppress stdout
> [prompt]> ffpython.exe ./code00.py > nul
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Check module
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\LucasG\DependenciesWalkerPolitistTexan\Version\DependenciesGui.exe" "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\lib\python3.10\site-packages\fontforge.pyd"
>
> [prompt]> :: Dependencies window pops up
> ```

And the (extension) module *Dependencies* ([[GitHub]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)) window:

[image: Img0]

Apparently, **everything works**, and the only logical conclusion one could draw, is that your environment is messed up.
Then I noticed a "small" detail: **you're using a virtual environment**.

**Output** (another (*Cmd*) terminal):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> :: Create VEnv (from FFPython)
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\python.exe" -m virtualenv -p "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0"
> created virtual environment CPython3.10.9.final.0-32 in 843ms
>   creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
>   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
>     added seed packages: pip==23.0.1, setuptools==67.4.0, wheel==0.38.4
>   activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0\bin\activate.bat"
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> :: Various tests
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" ./code00.py > nul
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> ffpython ./code00.py > nul
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> python ./code00.py > nul
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592\code00.py", line 14, in <module>
>     import fontforge as ff
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontforge'
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> :: View differences
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> ffpython ./code00.py
> Executable: C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe
> Version: 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit]
> CWD: E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592
> UName: None
> PATH: C:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
> PYTHONHOME: None
> PYTHONPATH: None
> sys.path: ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages']
> Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit] 032bit on win32
>
> <module 'fontforge' from 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages\\fontforge.pyd'>
> ['SpiroVersion', 'UnicodeAnnotationFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockCountFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockEndFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockNameFromLib', 'UnicodeBlockStartFromLib', 'UnicodeNameFromLib', 'UnicodeNames2FromLib', 'UnicodeNamesListVersion', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'activeFont', 'activeFontInUI', 'activeGlyph', 'activeLayer', 'ask', 'askChoices', 'askMulti', 'askString', 'awcontext', 'awglyph', 'configurePlugins', 'contour', 'cvt', 'defaultOtherSubrs', 'font', 'fonts', 'fontsInFile', 'getConvexNib', 'getPluginInfo', 'getPrefs', 'glyph', 'glyphPen', 'hasSpiro', 'hasUserInterface', 'hooks', 'layer', 'layer_array', 'layerinfo', 'layerinfo_array', 'loadEncodingFile', 'loadNamelist', 'loadNamelistDir', 'loadPlugins', 'loadPrefs', 'logWarning', 'math', 'mathKern', 'nameFromUnicode', 'onAppClosing', 'open', 'openFilename', 'parseTTInstrs', 'point', 'postError', 'postNotice', 'preloadCidmap', 'printSetup', 'private', 'readOtherSubrsFile', 'references', '
> registerGlyphSeparationHook', 'registerImportExport', 'registerMenuItem', 'runInitScripts', 'saveFilename', 'savePrefs', 'scriptFromUnicode', 'scriptPath', 'selection', 'setConvexNib', 'setPrefs', 'spiroCorner', 'spiroG2', 'spiroG4', 'spiroLeft', 'spiroOpen', 'spiroRight', 'splineCorner', 'splineCurve', 'splineHVCurve', 'splineTangent', 'unParseTTInstrs', 'unicodeFromName', 'unitShape', 'unspecifiedMathValue', 'userConfigPath', 'version']
>
> Done.
>
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> python ./code00.py
> Executable: C:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0\bin\python.exe
> Version: 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 09:16:22)  [GCC 12.2.0 32 bit]
> CWD: E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592
> UName: None
> PATH: C:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
> PYTHONHOME: None
> PYTHONPATH: None
> sys.path: ['e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10', 'C:\\Install\\pc032\\FontForge\\FontForgeBuilds\\Version\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackExchange\\StackOverflow\\q073506592', 'C:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages']
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592\code00.py", line 14, in <module>
>     import fontforge as ff
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontforge'
> ```

Looking at the *sys.path*'s last entry (in both cases), it becomes obvious why this happens.

So, this is a virtual environment related issue. To be more precise, it's a matter of virtual environment accessing the *site-packages* directory of the *Python* instance (system) it was created from.
In order to get past this, when creating the virtual environment, **pass the *--system-site-packages* flag**, mentioned in:

- [[PyPA.VirtualEnv]: CLI interface](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#cli-interface)
- [[Python.Docs]: venv - Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/library/venv.html)

**Output** (continued):

> ```
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff0) [prompt]> deactivate
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Create VEnv (from FFPython) - WITH --system-site-packages
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\python.exe" -m virtualenv -p "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" --system-site-packages "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff1"
> created virtual environment CPython3.10.9.final.0-32 in 859ms
>   creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff1, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=True)
>   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
>     added seed packages: pip==23.0.1, setuptools==67.4.0, wheel==0.38.4
>   activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test1ff1\bin\activate.bat"
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff1) [prompt]>  python ./code00.py > nul
>
> (py_pc032_03.10_test1ff1) [prompt]>
> ```

**Important note**:

- *Python* bundled by *FontForge* doesn't seem to be compatible with other "regular" *Python* instances, as it's:

  - Built with *GCC* (as opposed to *VStudio*). I think a consequence of that is its folder structure resembling to a *Nix* one
  - Crippled: lacks some standard modules (*SSL*, *HashLib*, ..)

  so attempting to load the *.pyd* by one of those (or virtual environments based on them) might yield ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*

**More debug info**

- *Cmd*:

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]> echo %PATH%
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" -c "import os;print(os.environ[\"PATH\"]);import fontforge;print(\"\nDone.\")"
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> where ffpython
  > INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
  >
  > [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
  >
  > [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin
  >
  > [prompt]> where ffpython
  > c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> ffpython -c "import os;print(os.environ[\"PATH\"]);import fontforge;print(\"\nDone.\")"
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *PowerShell* (*PS*):

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q073506592]> function prompt { "[PS prompt]> "; }
  > [PS prompt]>
  > [PS prompt]> ${Env:PATH}
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
  > [PS prompt]>
  > [PS prompt]> & "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe" -c "import os;print(os.environ[\`"PATH\`"]);import fontforge;print(\`"\nDone.\`")"
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
  >
  > Done.
  > [PS prompt]>
  > [PS prompt]> where.exe ffpython
  > INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
  > [PS prompt]>
  > [PS prompt]> ${Env:_PATH} = ${Env:PATH}
  > [PS prompt]> ${Env:PATH} = ${Env:_PATH} + "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin"
  > [PS prompt]> where.exe ffpython
  > c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\ffpython.exe
  > [PS prompt]>
  > [PS prompt]> ffpython -c "import os;print(os.environ[\`"PATH\`"]);import fontforge;print(\`"\nDone.\`")"
  > C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin;C:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin\
  >
  > Done.
  > ```

As seen, it works from *PS* as well, with no (or very few) manual interventions. If things don't work on your side, try running:

1. The above steps
2. *FFPython*, but from its directory
3. `ffpython -c "import os, sys;os.add_dll_directory(os.path.dirname(sys.executable));import fontforge"`

Useful when debugging these kind of errors:

- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546)
- [[SO]: Can't import Python module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56617906/4788546)

---

#### Update *#0*

After last findings, most likely some (older / newer version of) **dependent *.dll*s of *fontforge.pyd* are located in some directories listed in *%PATH%*, and they are loaded before the correct versions (from *FontForge*'s *bin* directory)**. That's a bit trickier to solve:

1. Read the 1<sup>st</sup> *URL* from the list above and install *Dependencies*.
2. Then you'll have to do a comparison of *fontforge.pyd*'s dependent *.dll*s when (*Dependencies* tool is) launched from:

   1. *FontForge*'s *bin* directory
   2. A different one

   Any *.dll*s that are in the former location **should not be present** (or if they are, they should have the same version) in any others (that come before it in *%PATH%*). You can either use the *GUI* version or the *CmdLine* one (like in the image below - *FontForge*'s *bin* directory on the right side):

   [image: Img1]

   The command that I used to list dependent *.dll*s (obviously, you'll have to adjust the paths):

   ```
   "c:\Install\pc064\LucasG\DependenciesWalkerPolitistTexan\Version\Dependencies.exe" -modules "c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\lib\python3.10\site-packages\fontforge.pyd" | findstr /R "\[Environment\] \[WindowsFolder\]"
   ```

   Another method is using *ProcMon* ([[MS.Learn]: Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)) when launching the script via *FFPython*, as shown in [[SO]: C DLL loads in C++ program, not in python Ctypes (@MarkTolonen's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650202/4788546)
3. Once you've found the "faulty" *.dll*s, either:

   1. Remove their directories from *%PATH%*. Actually, removing might be enough in this particular case, but in order to be certain that it will work in any circumstance (other directories containing "duplicates" might be present on some machines at some point) you should set it to some minimum that (is required for running any *Win* application and) works for you. You can do that either (again, I'm exemplifying on **my** *FontForge* installation directory - adapt it to yours and things should be fine):

      - By creating a *.bat* wrapper file:

        ```bat
        set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin

        ffpython script.py arg0, arg1 :: ...
        ```
      - From *script.py*:

        ```py
        import os
        os.environ["PATH"] = r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Install\pc032\FontForge\FontForgeBuilds\Version\bin"

        import fontforge as ff
        ```

      This way, loading the *.dll*(s) happens in a sandboxed environment (in regard to *%PATH%*), immune to any directories capable of messing things up.
   2. Of course, there's the (currently working, but a bit inconvenient) option of launching the script from *FontForge*'s *bin* directory (`cd ${FONTFORGE_BIN_DIR}` before launching the script)
   3. If any of the previous is not possible (for whatever reason - although I can't think of one at this point), remove (or better: rename) them (proceed with caution as applications that placed them there will (most likely) cease to work), but **only use this as a last resort**

Comment: I am extremely appreciative of your thorough reply and earnest help trying to get this solved. However, I don't think it's a VENV thing. I did a quick test and still run into the problem: https://i.imgur.com/PyQI5S4.png

The image above shows me using a vanilla powershell prompt to call `ffpython` and then attempting to import fontforge. Still get the error.

Any other ideas? Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the answer. Run the steps I indicated and also post the output, as the error alone doesn't help. What's the *Win* version? Any particularity that one should be aware of?

Comment: Ok! I'm getting somewhere now, but still confused. I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin` added to my system-wide PATH environment variable. When I feed PowerShell `${Env:PATH}` it returns all of my entries as expected, with the FontForge path at the end. To make sure, I checked `where.exe ffpython` and it returned the correct path to the executable. However when I then successively ran `ffpython -c "import os;print(os.environ["PATH"]);import fontforge;print("\nDone.")"` I yet again got the error (`ImportError: DLL load failed`).

Comment: However, when I simply navigated to the directory containing ffpython `(C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\)` ... and then ran the command again (`ffpython -c "import os;print(os.environ["PATH"]);import fontforge;print("\nDone.")")` it worked properly and I finally got no error.

So I'm happy I have a semi-working state but confused as to why things break when I call ffpython from another working directory. I'd like to be able to just call ffpython from any working directory I'm in.

Comment: FontForge version: `FontForge Windows build (32-bit) Sun, Jan  1, 2023  5:36:43 AM +0000 a1dad3e81da03d5d5f3c4c1c1b9b5ca5ebcfcecf [master] Based on master: a1dad3e81da03d5d5f3c4c1c1b9b5ca5ebcfcecf`

`https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/releases/download/20230101/FontForge-2023-01-01-Windows.exe`

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 22H2.

Comment: Lastly, `ffpython -c "import os, sys;os.add_dll_directory(os.path.dirname(sys.executable));import fontforge"` still returns `ImportError: DLL load failed` if I run the command outside of where ffpython is located. The only way I've been able to get things to work is by invoking ffpython from within its parent directory. Any more ideas?

Comment: Sorry, one last comment - I updated the post with the results of running your test script. Maybe that will help narrow things down.

Comment: Added a new update.

Comment: Using Dependencies I figured it out. Thank you so much. `libfontforge.dll` was referencing the wrong version of `zlib1.dll` from another directory I had in %PATH%. This is going to be problematic because I have quite a few applications with their own version of zlib1.dll that are added to PATH. Not sure how to handle that going forward but I suppose that is outside the scope of this problem. Thank you for your help, I would have never figured this out alone.

Comment: I wanted to say it might be *zlib1.dll* (as it's the most common). I edited the answer (adding more details that will hopefully get this issue solved).

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I actually had no idea that DLL files were leveraged from directories in %PATH%, I thought that only executable (exe's/bat/com/etc) files were rendered universally public. I think I just need to slim down my %PATH% variable and leverage full paths to utilities in my scrpits that  I use commonly use. It's nice to add all of my common applications to PATH so I can simply invoke them by name only, but I can see now it's creating more problems than solutions. Time to downsize. :)

Comment: I have a total of 9 instances of zlib1.dll in my %PATH%:

https://i.imgur.com/iyGUsdJ.png

This is bound to create conflicts. Renaming `zlib1.dll` to `zlib1.dll.old` fixed the problem, now I'm concerned other applications might not work  though,

Time to remove the the rogue zlib1.dll files from PATH.

Comment: instead of renaming, I'd suggest to manually set *PATH* (as I shown)because it's scalable, and it will work on any machine, and also on yours (if at a later time you'll install a new app that will add its *dir* containing a *.dll* in *PATH*).